# Bootstrap-switch odd behaviour

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap switch on my site which has been working fine,

Today I added some glyphs to my sidebar, which work fine however my switch (On a different page) looks very odd!

[image]

The jQuery code behind it is still working when I switch its state so I don't think that javascript is the issue here. Furthermore, this issue does not happen when viewed in Safari for iPad. I am seeing this in Chrome for the browser.

Any Ideas on how I can get my switch looking normal again.

Here is the HTML I have which creates it:

`<input name="my-checkbox" type="checkbox" checked  data-on-Color="success">`

Comment: Is it possible to privide working examples? I think this isn't solvable because my bet is 99% of your problem is NOT in the switch code.

Comment: Do you mean these working examples? http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/examples.html This is the only switch I have in my whole site

Comment: No I mean your page, with your code, working in our browser. That way we can check out what the cause of the problem is, instead of only knowing what you are trying to achieve. Please read this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: It seems like old browser or missing css (forgot a reference?) like @randy said, please create a snippet or bin or provide a link to your website (if it public)